# How can I parse data from an js object

Tags: javascript

I have a js data object, which contains some data. How can I parse f.e. the data for the key x, the key y and the key z?

I tried to use `json.parse(target, (key, value) => {console.log(value);})`

The object is:

```
{
  "x": 1.2246467991473532e-16,
  "y": 2,
  "z": -1
}
```

Comment: add that object then it would be easy to help you?

Comment: Did it (see above).

Comment: By "parse", do you mean to get a hash of double values indexed by keys x/y/z ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) object and get the properties from it.

```js
const obj = { x: 1.2246467991473532e-16, y: 2, z: -1 };
const { x, y, z } = obj;

console.log(x);
console.log(y);
console.log(z);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your iteration like this.

```js
const data = { x: "RGpr3Y6Q-1M", y: "btxdcqLOGuc", z: "btxdcqLOGuc" };

myIteration=( dataObj )=>{
  
  content = "" 
    for (const key in dataObj) {
        if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(dataObj , key)) {
            const element = dataObj[key];
            console.log( "key : " , key  ,  "value :" , element )
            content = content +  "key : "  +  key + "value :"  + element + "<br>"
        }
    }

}


myIteration( data )
document.getElementById("body").innerHTML = content
```

```html
 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
 

</head>
<body id="body">
    



 
 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all is worth for consider, for your case to use insted of js plain object, Map javascript structure
[Map structure](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

The main benefit for above structure compare to plain js object is to have any oppurtunity to declare diffrent than string type key. Thats why I highly recommended to use Map instead of fillings normal plain object after parsing.

But returning for your case. In javascript standart ( ES-2016 and upper ) method JSON.parse accept as first parameter appropriate string for example:

```
const json = '{"x": 12, "y":42, "z": 12}';
```

Than when in input you have any above appropriate string only than you can use for above string JSON.parse method without symantic error.

Than you can declare above calling for the const refenrence using

```
const jsonParse = JSON.parse(json)
```

Thats it :) I hope so this above anwser will be helpful for you ;)